# extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError) when `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.0'`

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.0'`, I got the following error.

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/someone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/ext/nokogiri
/Users/someone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/someone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200620-16406-16bp1ha.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/someone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
               CONFIG

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/someone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/someone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.5.0/gem_make.out
```

It looks like I have to modify the `extconf.rb` file. But where do I find that file?

Answer (score -1):

Try installing newer version:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8
```